# saving and downloading of excel file

Tags: javascript, excel

How to store an excel file in the database not in form of tables and rows but as a simple file and from database the file can be again brought and downloaded within the same form as excel file using jquery or javascript and db could be phpMyAdmin

Comment: Welcome Nikhil to StackOverFlow! First, this is not a write code site, you need to show some effort, and if you are stuck in something we may help! Also, `phpMyAdmin` is not a database, it's a tool used to handle the administration of MySQL. This link may help you http://www.w3programmers.com/file-upload-and-download-with-php/

Comment: Welcome! It's hard to understand what you're trying to do.  Check out "[ask]" as well as [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and also "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0):

Generally saving a file to Relational DB is not a good practice. You should not do it, unless you really need it. Have you considered saving it to a file system?

You can see the pros/cons list [here](https://habiletechnologies.com/blog/better-saving-files-database-file-system/).

If you have Non relational database, than you should be good to go. You can find more information [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb) (Mongo details).